# Angular checkbox first click does nothing if ng-checked is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, this seems like it must be a newb question. Here is a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/r9xWht5DZtOTvbblXwYZ

```
<input id="reviews"  ng-model="reviews" type="checkbox" ng-checked="reviews == 1" />
```

Basically I have a boolean in the db that I set scope to, it is either 1 or 0 in db. If it is true then the checkbox is checked, if not then it isn't. The problem I am having is that if it is checked, the first time 1 uncheck the box, scope doesn't change. When I click it (check it again) the scope value turns into true, then it works as expected.

Again, I must be overlooking something trivial here. I was looking into $scope.$watch should I be using that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ng-checked` you can use [`ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) instead.

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/74ASYrXYCdF1H1FyxFBi?p=preview)

```
<input id="reviews"  ng-model="reviews" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
```

Comment: I just came back to answer my question with this, that was fast!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is using `ng-checked` with `ng-model`. The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) says:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as
>   this can lead to unexpected behavior.

Both try to set the value of the input field and this leads to the weird results you're having.